# Локальные принтеры(usb) в hp web jetadmin

Tags: железо

Как найти локальные принтеры (которые подключены через usb) в `hp jetadmin`.

Принтеры подключенные через сеть находит сразу, а которые через `usb` - не видит.

Даже не обнаруживает тот принтер , который подключен к компу с jetadmin.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что относится к проблемам с hardware

Comment: Скороее всего никак, если нет ActiveDirectory. Принтеры подлюченные через windows не публикуют себя через бродкаст.

Comment: Через AD тоже не находит....